# Gráfico de barras ggplot2 - R

Tags: r, ggplot2, gráfico

Tenho o dataframe a seguir e gostaria de fazer um único gráfico que comparasse as categorias da minha coluna Freq

```
  Var1 num                 Freq
1    0 394 Frequência observada
2    1 341 Frequência observada
3    2 168 Frequência observada
4    3  42 Frequência observada
5    4  14 Frequência observada
6    5   4 Frequência observada
7    0 377 Frequência teórica
```

Usei o código a seguir, mas o resultado é um gráfico que soma os resultados na coluna "num" para minhas duas categorias da coluna "Freq"

```
graf1<-ggplot(teste3) +
  geom_bar(mapping=aes(y = num, x = Var1, fill=Freq),alpha=0.5, stat = "identity") +
  labs(x = "Parturição",y="Frequência")+
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Dark2", name="Distribuição", labels=c("Observada", "Teórica"))
```

[image: Resultado do gráfico de barras]

Precisava que os resultados das categorias não fossem somados e  fossem apresentados em um mesmo gráfico (indicando a comparação do tamanho das colunas para cada categoria do meu eixo x)

Comment: Use o argumento `position="dodge"` dentro da função `geom_bar()`.

Answer (score 1):

Como bem dito pelo Marcus Nunes, `position = "dodge"` atende ao que você precisa:

```
library(tidyverse)
```

Primeiro, um exemplo reprodutível do seu dataset:

```
teste3 <- tibble::tribble(
  ~Var1, ~num,                  ~Freq,
     0, 394, "Frequência observada",
     1, 341, "Frequência observada",
     2, 168, "Frequência observada",
     3,  42, "Frequência observada",
     4,  14, "Frequência observada",
     5,   4, "Frequência observada",
     0, 377,   "Frequência teórica")
```

Em seguida, o plot com o argumento `position = "dodge"`

```
ggplot(teste3) +
  geom_bar(mapping=aes(y = num, x = Var1, fill=Freq),
           alpha=0.5, 
           stat = "identity", 
           position = "dodge") +
  labs(x = "Parturição",y="Frequência")+
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Dark2", name="Distribuição", labels=c("Observada", "Teórica"))
```

Resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

*Observação:* atente apenas para o fato de que os dados que vc disponibilizou não correspondem ao gráfico que você usou para plotar o seu exemplo. Creio que vc deve ter postado os dados de uma tentativa e o gráfico de outra.